# Maven detects wrong java path

Tags: java, macos, maven, terminal

Every time I run

```
mvn -version
```

it says:

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.   We cannot execute
>   /usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin/java

However, I don't use openJDK anymore. I deleted it a long time ago.
WHERE is maven referencing this path, and how do I change it?
I am not talking about changing JAVA_HOME environment variable.
I want to know where this path & error message is coming from in maven config.

I just want to set my computer's java to 1.8, that's all. Why is maven picking up an uninstalled, old version of openJDK ?

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
mvn -v                                                                    
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin/java
```

Comment: Run `set -x` in the shell and then `mvn -version`. There will be a lot of output but you will see what `mvn` script does.

Comment: you need to set your java home as "export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home" put it on your .bash_profile or .zshrc

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows:

**one time solution(in case you don't have access to set the system path)**

in cmd prompt run below
set PATH="YOUR/PATH/TO/JDK/BIN/";%PATH%
set JAVA_HOME="YOUR/PATH/TO/JDK"

then run java -version and mvn -v IN THE SAME SESSION OF CMD PROMPT

long term solution:
edit systempath and add you YOUR/PATH/TO/JDK/BIN/; in front of rest of the paths.

### If you are using Linux

export path= /YOUR/PATH/TO/JDK/BIN/:$path
export JAVA_HOME=/YOUR/PATH/TO/JDK

### long term solution

in .bash_profile add above 2 lines and restart the shell.